# Combining Sencha Touch with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sencha-touch

I have been working in Sencha Touch for a few weeks now, and while the framework is very powerful, I still find areas of it difficult to work with, particularly the JSONP data stores for complex nested JSON results. As a result, I decided to combine the useful AJAX and JSON functions of jQuery for adding items to a DataStore already coded in Sencha Touch.

I just wondered if anyone else has similar difficulties with the API for Sencha Touch, and has been using jQuery with the framework. What are the performance implications of this, and is it advisable to use only Sencha Touch methods?

Comment: well, i'm wondering also: are jquery's DOM traversal methods faster-enough in comparison to Ext that it merits including jQuery? The extra download does suck, but when compared to Sencha's whopping 2xxkb (oh but it's only 80kb if gzipped! :P), it seems worth it to me if only to save on bytes due to jquery's help in making code terse. thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am including jQuery in my Sencha Touch based application and so far haven't seen any problems with it. I'm using jQuery mostly for accessing and updating values in my custom HTML code (e.g. stuff inside the html attribute of a Sencha Touch component).

It will naturally be more heavy if you include another library (jQuery) but the difference in performance is not noticeable in my opinion. I have only however tested on the browser and not on a mobile device. The difference in performance could be more noticeable if the user is using a 3G connection on a mobile device.

But if I were you, I would probably use the existing API when it comes to adding/removing stuff from a DataStore. Which part do you find difficult in using a DataStore with the existing API?

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! I have now re-written the section to use Ext's JSONP namespace and it does seem slightly quicker at parsing the results back into a data store. I guess only one loop is involved, rather than the two I was using by combining it with jQuery.

Comment: How should the jquery library be included actually? I can't get it to work properly. I've included it in my index.html file and wrote a small click event function and it doesnt work : |

Thread i started if you'd care to see the source code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931404/jquery-library-not-working-with-sencha-touch