# How general is Sencha Touchs javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Sencha Touch seems like an amazing way to develop mobile apps.  I've seen posts by people incorporating [Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351133/combining-sencha-touch-with-jquery), [D3](http://wpdojo.net/other-web-development-news/jobs/sencha-touch-html5-d3-js-protovis-125-150k-redwood-city/).

At the same time the posts describing customizing controls seems to be [fairly narrow](http://robertdougan.com/posts/taking-advantage-of-componentview-in-sencha-touch-2).
Adding the picture of a kitten next to the slider and labeling the slider seems kinda tame compared to what ios can do in terms of [custom controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/), at least in terms of examples available.   Most blog posts imply you can extend the control objects in Sencha or the CSS file.

These posts are not quite what I'm looking for - that's my problem. I can't see any examples of anyone changing default controls in Sencha touch, but they make it sound as if it might be possible to do anything.

This is my question:

**Is Sencha Touch able to build an iOS or Android App incorporating *any* javascript library or HTML5?  Are there any limitations here?**

To give an example I trying to implement a custom slider, where a touch along a continuous line or a circle like [this color selector](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ancolorpicker) will enter new values. Further if you incorporate a library like protovis or D3 (or Raphael charts) can Sencha display anything the graph canvas element will otherwise display?  Will it take touch input and interact with the graph libraries the way that [the HTML5 graph does](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/force.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you mentioned is not about customizing controls, it's about displaying a list from bound store, instead of of using just `Ext.XTemplate` (the system with `Ext.view.View`) to generate HTML, it uses `ComponentView` to generate `Ext.Component`s instead.

It's hard to tell what you're asking, what in particular are you trying to do?

To address some of the questions you added:

- Charts in Sencha are implemented using Raphael, which uses SVG, therefore all the elements in the chart can be interacted with using HTML events.
- Everything that Sencha generates is valid HTML, you can listen to HTML events, but components usually abstract the lower level events into something that is easier to consume, (for example a data view abstracts the click so that it passes the record being clicked along with the event).

Therefore, the answer to the question is, **YES**, Sencha can co-exist with regular HTML. If you want the full benefit of the framework, you should always create an `Ext.Component` so that your components can be easily used within the framework's layout containers.

It's very easy to misuse Ext when trying to write regular HTML and still place that within the layout rendering pipeline. `Ext.Component` has a built in way of creating HTML out of templates, see http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-data and http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-tpl

Comment: changed question in bold. want to know if i can customize controls with any javascript library i please within the sencha framework and get it to build apps properly.

Comment: Your question is still to broad. There are limitations, but you haven't narrowed your question enough, I am not going to list every limitation I can think of.

Comment: ok amended further.  would like to have some general ideas where the limitations are if you can talk to that too though.